# Local Project Dependencies and Maven

Tags: netbeans, maven, build, dependencies

I'm converting an ant backed Netbeans project into an Maven project. I've got most of the third party libraries set up in the POM, however now I've run into problems with setting up the local dependencies.

With the previous Netbeans way of doing things, it just added a project reference [with links to the source and jar location, rebuilt the dependency if the depedency's source had been changed and hadn't been compiled]. However I'm not sure how to setup up Maven to emulate this behavior. Is it possible?

Example:

```
Projects/SharedLibrariesResource [Ant based project]
Projects/WebSite [this is a maven based project]
Projects/Client
```

In this example the website and client projects don't connect to each other, but they do share the SharedLibrariesResource. Website should compile to produce a War with links to the SharedLibrariesResource

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the question, the `Website` maven project depends on the ant `SharedLibrariesResource` project.  When `Website` is built, it should include the `SharedLibrariesResource` artifacts.  The assumption is `SharedLibrariesResources` produces a `jar` artifact.

One way to achieve this is to

- install `SharedLibrariesResource` to your local maven repository each time ant builds it
- specify this as a dependency in `Website` pom.

We can use [maven ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html) to achieve the first.

Comment: The projects "Website" and Client are two disconnected projects that depend on the "SharedLibraryResources" project